# FTP протокол, ответ на запрос LIST, какие данные за что отвечают?

Tags: ftp

Вот я получил такой ответ отсюда: ftp://ftp.drweb.com/pub/drweb/android/light/

```
drwxrwxrwx    5 505      505          4096 Feb 11 15:05 HTML
-rw-rw-r--    1 505      505       1980414 May 05 06:22 drweb-600-android-en.pdf
-rw-rw-r--    1 505      505       1794207 May 05 06:22 drweb-600-android-fr.pdf
-rw-rw-r--    1 505      505        962768 May 05 06:21 drweb-600-android-light.apk
-rw-rw-r--    1 505      505       1008251 May 05 06:22 drweb-600-android-ru.pdf
```

Первый столбец это права, 5 это размер. Как я понял у директории размер 4096. Потом дата изменения и имя файла(директории). 
Собственно вопрос, что такое остальные столбцы. Спецификацию FTP читал, видимо у мну с английским плохо или я слепой - не нашел, что они значат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-rw-rw-r--    1 505      505       1008251 May 05 06:22 [drweb-600-android-ru.pdf](http://drweb-600-android-ru.pdf)

chmod      user/group     n/a       size      date           filename

кажется так, где n/a это я не помню, может и ни группа пользователя не помню